# How to load lazy loaded angular script chunks via Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, lazy-loading

Switched angular 9 app to lazy loading to reduce main.js bundle size.
Works fine locally and loads the module upon hitting the route.

e.g. downloads the script *http://localhost:port/name-module.js*

After running **npm run build** the chunks are produced for all routes.

Since I'm loading my Angular app via Node.js Express app I have a html file where I included the main scripts.

e.g.

```
<script src="./angular/runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="./angular/polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="./angular/main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
```

Obviously, I need to include my chunks as well but thought the code would be in main.js to fetch the required chunk when the corresponding route is hit? In other words I don't have to explicitly define the script for those chunks in the html file shown above.

The error which I'm getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 2 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:5000/2-es2015.js)
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 2 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:5000/2-es2015.js)
```

Comment: check in your .html the base tag in the headers, I suppose should be like `<base href="/angular/">`. Angular take account of this to look for the lazzing loading files

Comment: This works but the there is another problem ofcourse I get /angular/ appended to my routes which won't work. Is there a way to point to /angular/ for lazy load but retain the base href="/" as it is?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if it's possible, BTW you can copy manually the "chunks" files to the "root" folder -where you has the index.html-